# \section, \subsection-derived commands end up twice in TOC, along with some floating 1s

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{hoofdstuk}            % Define hoofdstuk counter independently
\newcounter{afdeling}[hoofdstuk]  % Define afdeling counter within the hoofdstuk counter
\newcounter{artikel}[hoofdstuk]   % Define artikel counter within the hoofdstuk counter

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hoofdstuk}[1]{%
  \@startsection
    {hoofdstuk}%                                                                  name
    {1}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                           before skip
    {2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries Hoofdstuk\ \thehoofdstuk. #1}%                    style
    %{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Hoofdstuk\ \thehoofdstuk. #1}}%               Add to TOC
}

\newcommand{\afdeling}[1]{%
  \@startsection
    {afdeling}%                                                                   name
    {2}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                          before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries Afdeling\ \thehoofdstuk.\theafdeling. #1}%        style
}

\newcommand{\artikel}[1]{%
  \@startsection
    {artikel}%                                                                    name
    {2}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                          before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\bfseries Artikel\ \thehoofdstuk.\theartikel. (#1)}%              style
    %{\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Artikel\ \thehoofdstuk.\theartikel. (#1)}}%  Add to TOC
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{hoofdstuk}{0}
\setcounter{afdeling}{0}
\tableofcontents
\hoofdstuk{Algemene}
\afdeling{Begrippen}
\artikel{begrippen}
Some text.
\artikel{artikel}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Per the first comment, I have successfully removed the `refstepcounter`, which has removed the factor two increase from the counters. However, removing the TOC-related command leaves me with an empty TOC.

Furthermore, the \afdeling command seems to have broken somewhat, and I have no idea what's going on with the body text now.

[image]

---

### Original

I have attempted to make some custom headings based off of the (sub)section command. However, it sort of ends up twice in the TOC and there are some floating numbers in there, so I've done something wrong.

Furthermore, the counter appears to increase with a factor two rather than +1, and I've got another number behind my section title. The headings should be formatted 'Hoofdstuk 1. Title', 'Afdeling 1.1. Title', and 'Artikel 1.1. (title)', and I'm not entirely sure where those numbers behind them came from. Although I am happy they are not in the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{hoofdstuk}            % Define hoofdstuk counter independently
\newcounter{afdeling}[hoofdstuk]  % Define afdeling counter within the hoofdstuk counter
\newcounter{artikel}[hoofdstuk]   % Define artikel counter within the hoofdstuk counter

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hoofdstuk}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{hoofdstuk}%                                                     Increment hoofdstuk counter
  \@startsection
    {hoofdstuk}%                                                                  name
    {1}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                           before skip
    {2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries Hoofdstuk\ \thehoofdstuk. #1}%                    style
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Hoofdstuk\ \thehoofdstuk. #1}}%               Add to TOC
}

\newcommand{\afdeling}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{afdeling}%                                                      Increment afdeling counter
  \@startsection
    {afdeling}%                                                                   name
    {2}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                          before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries Afdeling\ \thehoofdstuk.\theafdeling. #1}%        style
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Afdeling\ \thehoofdstuk.\theafdeling. #1}}%Add to TOC
}

\newcommand{\artikel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{artikel}%                                                       Increment artikel counter
  \@startsection
    {artikel}%                                                                    name
    {2}%                                                                          level
    {\z@}%                                                                        indent
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                          before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                          after skip
    {\normalfont\bfseries Artikel\ \thehoofdstuk.\theartikel. (#1)}%              style
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Artikel\ \thehoofdstuk.\theartikel. (#1)}}%  Add to TOC
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{hoofdstuk}{0}
\setcounter{afdeling}{0}
\tableofcontents
\hoofdstuk{Algemene}
\afdeling{Begrippen}
\artikel{begrippen}
Some text.
\artikel{artikel}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for getting your eyes on here. Any thoughts'd be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: check the standard \section definition in e.g. article.cls. They do not add \addcontentsline or \refstepcounter.

Comment: Why create completely new commands and not change the existing ones to include the tekst "artikel" and "afdeling"?

Comment: Or why not `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` and let the package take care of translating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{hoofdstuk}            % Define hoofdstuk counter independently
\newcounter{afdeling}[hoofdstuk]  % Define afdeling counter within the hoofdstuk counter
\newcounter{artikel}[afdeling]    % Define artikel counter within the afdeling counter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thehoofdstuk}{\arabic{hoofdstuk}}  % Remove chapter prefix from hoofdstuk numbering
\renewcommand{\theafdeling}{\thehoofdstuk.\arabic{afdeling}}  % Include hoofdstuk prefix in afdeling numbering
\renewcommand{\theartikel}{\thehoofdstuk.\arabic{artikel}}  % Include afdeling prefix in artikel numbering

\newcommand{\hoofdstuk}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{hoofdstuk}% Increment hoofdstuk counter
  \section*{Hoofdstuk \thehoofdstuk. #1}%                    style
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Hoofdstuk \thehoofdstuk. #1}
}

\newcommand{\afdeling}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{afdeling}% Increment afdeling counter
  \subsection*{Afdeling \theafdeling. #1}%        style
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Afdeling \theafdeling. #1}
}

\newcommand{\artikel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{artikel}% Increment artikel counter
  \subsection*{Artikel \theartikel. (#1)}%              style
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Artikel \theartikel. (#1)}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{hoofdstuk}{0}
\setcounter{afdeling}{0}
\tableofcontents
\hoofdstuk{Algemene}
\afdeling{Begrippen}
\artikel{begrippen}
Some text.
\artikel{artikel}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]